# Override my default parameters in my plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

Ive been trying to convert my carosel function to a plugin my problem is that I want to be able to override the default parameters so I can change the variables from another javascript file.

```
(function($){
$.rjm_carosel = (function(rjm){

    var sums = $(window).width() / 2;
    var animating = false;
    var step = 0;
    var nextStep = 0;
    var prevStep = 0;
    var defaults = {
                    mainContainer: ".container",
                    delay: 15000,
                    slideDuration: 1000,
                    slideEasing: "easeOutQuart",
                    };      


    rjm.reclass_thumb_blocks = function(){

    };

    rjm.slideNext = function(){

    };

    rjm.slideBack = function(){

    };

    rjm.bindBtn = function(){

    };

    rjm.unbindBtn = function(){

    };
    return rjm;

})({});

})(jQuery);
```

This is what I do to trigger the functions in another js file which work:

```
        $.rjm_carosel.unbindBtn();
        $.rjm_carosel.bindBtn();
        $.rjm_carosel.reclass_thumb_blocks();
```

**How can I override say mainContainer default variable to be '.newWrapper' instead of '.container'?**

I want to be able to overide the defaults outside the plugins js file otherwise its no use to me.

Answer (score 0):

Addy Osmani has a nice template that demonstrates how to set defaults and then be able to override them. Should be just what you need. [Here is a link to it on Github.](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.best.options.plugin-boilerplate.js)

Ad here is the tl;dr: In essence you set up a var to extend the defaults:

```
    options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.pluginName.options, options );

    return this.each(function () {

        var elem = $(this);

    });
};
```

and then you can actually set defaults in case nothing is passed in with:

```
$.fn.pluginName.options = {

    key: "value",
    myMethod: function ( elem, param ) {

    }
};
```

to override you would use:

```
$.fn.pluginName.key ='otherval';
```